# Android ExpandableListView indicator/icon always stretched

Tags: android, icons, expandablelistview, stretch, indicator

I use my own icon image as indicator for ExpandableListView, but the icon seems to be stretched, I tried to put the image file in /drawable and /drawable-hdpi with no luck. If I do not use my own icon, the built-in Android one looks nice, so I wonder is there any restriction on image dimension, or is there anything I've done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: group_indicator.9.png]

Whatever image you are using as your group indicator, make it a 9 patch (xxx.9.png) image and set its stretchable areas to around the border pixels (which probably may be transparent). It will prevent stretching of image from the middle.

Comment: its not working.... there is no change if we set the 9 patch image .....

one solution i apply is that make the arrow image of the same height as background of where it display.....

Comment: @PavanKumar it depends on what size you do need. :)

Comment: Worked fine for me. Besides, I found a link that might help clarify things: https://www.hrupin.com/2012/08/how-to-create-custom-groupindicator-for-expandablelistview-group

Answer (score 7):

The expandable list is a pain. It always stretches the icons. An easy solution is to use a nine patches images which contains only a stretchable pixel at both top and bottom. Thus only those two pixels are stretched and the rest of your image remains unmodified.

hope this make sense

Comment: "only a stretchable pixel at both top and bottom", does it mean there is no stretchable pixel on left/right?

Comment: also, my icons is a solid circle with a triangle inside, it looks like impossible to make this to be a nine patch.

Comment: when I do not use my own icon, the Android's built-in icon is not stretched, so I suppose there is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: to see an example, search for expander_ic_maximized.9 in the Android resources folder. That is the icon that Android uses by default for expandable list and it has the pixels that I mentioned.

Comment: thanks, it looks like expander_ic_maximized.9 is a nine patch image, but in my case, it is impossible to make it nine patch, also, even it is nine patch, it appears smaller than my stretched icon.

Comment: As "it always stretches", so I just accept your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this all via coding, without using a different image, this is how I got this working.

(1) Setting the group indicator to null

(2) Including my custom group indicator in the group Layout.

(3) Having an `groupClickListener` that changes the state of you indicator.

Code Snippets :

(1) `mListView.setGroupIndicator(null);`

(2) Included my indicator in the group layout.

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/help_group_indicator"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/help_group_indicator_dimension"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/help_group_indicator_dimension"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/help_group_indicator_dimension"
    android:src="@drawable/down_icon" />
```

(3)

```
mListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View clickedView, int groupPosition, long rowId) {
        ImageView groupIndicator = (ImageView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.help_group_indicator);
        if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
            parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            groupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_icon);
        } else {
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            groupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_icon);
         }
        return true;
    }
});
```